# Prefix_action, suffix_action with sequences

Tags: ocaml

I want to write a function prefix_action with seq (resp suffix_action), here is the code in BatEnum :

```
 let prefix_action f t =
  let full_action e =
    e.count <- (fun () -> t.count());
    e.next  <- (fun () -> t.next ());
    e.clone <- (fun () -> t.clone());
    f ()
  in
  let rec t' =
    {
      count = (fun () -> full_action t'; t.count() );
      next  = (fun () -> full_action t'; t.next()  );
      clone = (fun () -> full_action t'; t.clone() );
      fast  = t.fast
    } in t'
```

I want to know as we don't have clone in sequences, i want to know how i should considerate clone in these case (is it a use of the sequence) and if that's the case how can we have the number of times that the sequence is used?
[Prefix_action Documentation](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview:batteries-beta1/html/api/Enum.html#VALprefix_action)

Comment: The link is broken, probably you need to delete `=` character at the end of the link.

Comment: already done, sorry

Comment: honestly, it is totally unclear what are you asking... are creating your own sequence type that doesn't have clones? If yes, then you need to provide the type definition.

Comment: not my own sequence, there is a data structure in Batteries called Sequence and it doesn't have clone `type 'a node =
  | Nil
  | Cons of 'a * 'a t

and 'a t = unit -> 'a node
`

Answer (score 4):

The sequence as it is defined don't have clone function just because it is "defined by default".

```
type 'a node =
|   Nil
|   Cons of 'a * 'a t
and 'a t = unit -> 'a node
```

As you can see it's just a function returning some sum type, simple value if you wish, there is no side effects (in fact they can be hiden in the body of the function, but for now let me trick you). Thus the clone function in this case is just an identity:

```
let clone s = s
```

Now if you look at the definition of enumeration you will notice little `mutable` keyword:

```
type 'a t = { 
  mutable count : unit -> int;
  mutable next  : unit -> 'a;
  mutable clone : unit -> 'a t;
  mutable fast  : bool;
}
```

If we try to use same `clone` as for sequences, we will notice that the changes of one copy will affect the other:

```
# let e1 = { fast = true; (* ... *) };;
val e1 : 'a t = {fast = true; (* ... *)}
# let e2 = clone e1;;
val e2 : 'a t = {fast = true; (* ... *)}
# e1.fast <- false;;
- : unit = ()
# e2;;
'a t = {fast = false; (* ... *)}
```

That's why they need `clone` function.

So now you can implement your functions, for example `prefix_action`.

> `prefix_action f e` will behave as `e` but guarantees that `f ()` will be
>   invoked exactly once before the current first element of `e` is read.

The problem is in this *"exactly once"*. I'm not sure what does it means, but let say that this means that if you pass sequence to `prefix_action f` and then two times to `hd`, then `f` will be executed only once (because if it means something different it's not interesting). And now we can return to this "side effects" story. Clearly, we can't implement `prefix_action` without them. The type of sequence doesn't contain any `mutable` keyword, but it contains functions! Hence, we can wrap our side effect into the function.

```
let prefix_action : (unit -> unit) -> 'a t -> 'a t = fun f s ->
    let b = ref true in
    fun () -> (if !b then f (); b := false); s ()
```

But now, as we have side effects, we need redefine `clone`. From the specification of `prefix_action`:

> If `prefix_action f e` is cloned, `f` is invoked only once, during the
>   cloning.

Hence our `clone`:

```
let clone s = let _ = s (); s
```